# On Spotify's new Facebook integration settings section, what does the "unhide people" dropdown do?

Tags: facebook, spotify

I'm using Spotify's Windows client software.  The 'Unhide People' setting is explained nowhere.  Spotify's general explanation about Facebook sharing can be found [on their blog](https://www.spotify.com/us/blog/archives/2011/09/27/what-to-share/).

From the screenshot on that post the settings look like this:
[image: Screenshot from Spotify blog]

This is what the setting looks like in my Spotify Windows client.
[image: Windows Spotify client settings]

They changed the checkbox wording a little bit but more concerning is the fact that I can't find the description of the Unhide People dropdown anywhere.  I posted on the Spotify blog with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setting is now gone so this question is irrelevant...

[image: replaced with 'Private Listening']